# Image is not fit into QuickContactBadge

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have create a listview of Contact numbers , the list item contains the `QuickContactBadge` and `TextView` now whenever i tried to load image into QuickContactBadge it `does not get fit into` the QuickContactBadge Frame and at the same time `QuickBadgeContact itself will also get shrink.`

Rite now i have this

[image]

What i am trying to achieve is

[image]

so not only image but even i am trying to make QuickContactBadge of a normal size

here is my code that i am using

```
    Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
                             String.valueOf(contactId));

    InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream
                            (
                            getContentResolver(), contactUri
                            );


 cache.photoView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input));
```

My Layout for list item

```
<QuickContactBadge
        android:id="@+id/badge"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
        android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_contact_picture"
        style="?android:attr/quickContactBadgeStyleWindowSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:paddingLeft="2dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/badge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: //try hard code android:layout_height= "50dp"        android:layout_width= "50dp"

Comment: @PadmaKumar  u r comment works you can put it into answer too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//try hard code your layout height and width

```
android:layout_height= "50dp" android:layout_width= "50dp"
```

//make sure that use dp/dip this fill fit for all your screen resolution

suppose your 50dp for mdpi will be same 50px

```
mdpi 50*160/160=50px
hdpi 50*240/160=75px
xhdpi 50*320/160=100px
```